# C++ C'tor does not initialize fields?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization

In C++11 I wrote:

```
JobsList::JobEntry::JobEntry(pid_t pid, pid_t jid, const string &cmd, bool is_stopped) : pid(pid), jid(jid), cmd(cmd),
                                                                                         is_stopped(is_stopped) {
    time(&insertion_time);
}
```

But the compiler keeps giving me warning:

```
Clang-Tidy: Constructor does not initialize these fields: insertion_time
```

How can I get rid of this and initialize in_time?

Comment: Show some [mre] - an entire (but reduced) C++ translation unit. Before that, read [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and a good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html)

Comment: It's not a compiler, it's clang-tidy, a static analysis tool, giving you this warning. Presumably, false positive. You can suppress it.

Comment: @yeputons can't I call time function in initialization list?

Comment: @stacker You can not. You can work around with immediately invoked lambda expression, but it looks ugly. It's better to make your own wrapper of `time()` which returns `time_t` instead of using output arguments, and call it.

Answer (score 2):

You have an initialization list, in which you don't initialize `insertion_time`.

In the body of the constructor, **after** initialization of the fields, you set the value of `insertion_time` through a call to `time()`.

Clang-Tidy then warns you that this field has not been initialized but is being used.

You may initialize it with something like:

```
 JobsList::JobEntry::JobEntry(pid_t pid, pid_t jid, const string &cmd, bool is_stopped) : pid(pid), jid(jid), cmd(cmd), is_stopped(is_stopped), insertion_time(0) {
    time(&insertion_time);
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can use `time()` in the initialization list, but not by using `time(&insertion_time)`. You have to call `insertion_time(time(nullptr))` instead. The `time()` function returns the correct value:

```
JobsList::JobEntry::JobEntry(pid_t pid, pid_t jid, const string &cmd, bool is_stopped) : pid(pid), jid(jid), cmd(cmd), is_stopped(is_stopped), insertion_time(time(nullptr)) {
}
```

Comment: can't I call time function in initialization list?

Comment: thanks, last thing what time(&insertion_time) returns?

Comment: the same value that is used to set `insertion_time`. Read manual.

Comment: so we can replace your edit with insertion_time(time(insertion_time))?

Comment: No don't. Why would you want such a thing. My proposal will initialize your field, what are you excpecting more ?

Comment: I mean in does have the same impact since you said: "the same value that is used to set insertion_time"

Comment: In many place you can use time(&it) or it=time(nullptr). In initialisation list only it(time(nullptr)) is valid.And there is no interesting thing to obtain by calling it = time(&it) when it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
time_t time (time_t* timer);
```

So [`time`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/) returns a `time_t`

```
JobsList::JobEntry::JobEntry(pid_t pid, pid_t jid, const string &cmd, bool is_stopped) : pid(pid), jid(jid), cmd(cmd), is_stopped(is_stopped), 
insertion_time(time(nullptr)) {
}
```